# Python 3.2 TypeError - can't figure out what it means

Tags: python-3.x

I originally put this code through Python 2.7 but needed to move to Python 3.x because of work.  I've been trying to figure out how to get this code to work in Python 3.2, with no luck.

```
import subprocess
cmd = subprocess.Popen('net use', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout:
    if 'no' in line:
        print (line)
```

I get this error

```
if 'no' in (line):
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Can anyone provide me with an answer as to why this is and/or some documentation to read?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 uses the `bytes` type in a lot places where the encoding is not clearly defined. The `stdout` of your subprocess is a file object working with bytes data. So, you cannot check if there is some string within a bytes object, e.g.:

```
>>> 'no' in b'some bytes string'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    'no' in b'some bytes string'
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

What you need to do instead is a test if the bytes string contains another *bytes* string:

```
>>> b'no' in b'some bytes string'
False
```

So, back to your problem, this should work:

```
if b'no' in line:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you very much.  Time to read up on bytes a little more.